# A way to share data between classes not using singleton

Tags: java

I am working on library that is used in application (as Maven artifact). In my current situation library has a main class that provides static methods for working with it. Therefore it allows only "one instance" work mode with this library. At the beginning of work it is necessary to provide `Configuration` object to this main class. Such as `MainClass.start(new Configuration())` and later on this configuration object is accessed by other classes via singleton factory.

My problem currently is that I need to change library in a way that it should allow multi-instance mode. Such that `MainClass` won't have any more static methods, and will have to be instantiated. What I stumble upon is how do I then provide each instance with its unique `Configuration` in a way that instances of other classes (those that are used together with current instance of MainClass) can also access it while not having direct access to instance of MainClass. Of course in this scenario Singleton isn't a solution because two or more `MainClass` instances should have each own configuration.

Comment: I think when you instantiate MainClass you also instantiate the others or pass the configuration the as parameter

Comment: @HankLapidez Maybe I should extend question some more - in short - yes, some objects may be instantiated within MainClass constructor, but some are instantiated only on certain events and those are not instantiated in MainClass, but in some other classes. It will be a pure pain passing Configuration object everywhere, though that is backup way I am considering, but I am looking for some other (maybe easier or more proper) way to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Configuration{
 String a;
 String b;

 public Configuration(String a, String b){
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
 }

 public String getA(){
  return a;
 }

 public String getB(){
  return b;
 }

}


class MainClassFactory{
 private final static MainClassFactory INSTANCE = new MainClassFactory();
 private ConcurrentHashMap<String,MainClass> mainClassMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,MainClass>();
 public static getInstance(){
  return INSTANCE;
 }

 public MainClass getMainClass(Configuration config){
  String key = config.getA() +","+ config.getB();
  MainClass mainClass = mainClassMap.get(key);
  if(mainClass == null){
   mainClass = new MainClass(config);
   mainClassMap.put(key,mainClass);
  }
  return mainClass;
 }

}
```

Will this help you ?

Assuming the `MainClass` instantiate with `Configuration` 
then by calling `MainClassFactory.getInstance().getMainClass(config)` you will be able to get the same MainClass by "same" configuration (the "same" here means the value of a and b are the same)

The idea is simple: use a key with can represent the characteristic of the `Configuration` and cache the `MainClass` using a Map with this key.
Finally return the same object when providing configuration with same characteristic;

Comment: How would I get then configuration from some OtherClass object which has no idea under which MainClass object it is operating?

Comment: @AlexKey Do you mean the `OtherClass` want to use the `MainClass` method but have no idea on which Configuration it should pass to `MainClassFactory` ?

Comment: No, `OtherClass` does not use `MainClass` methods, but instead it is instantiated at runtime and has no idea about `MainClass` and its public methods are being called by `MainClass`. Since it has no idea about `MainClass`, there is no way from your code for me to get appropriate `Configuration` object.

Comment: You can look at  Hank Lapidez solution in comments, but it is far not ideal as I will have to pass Configuration object everywhere around.